# Opening a file using a UWP app from the shell/command line

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-explorer, shell, uwp

I need to be able to open certain file types using a UWP app from by using the command shell to pass the file name as a parameter.

The file type I am trying to open with multiple apps is `.3mf`, used for 3D objects.

I have created a application which sets itself as a default for a certain file type, and this application needs to ask the user upon launch to open the file with another application. The issue is that I need to add 3D builder as a option in this list.

Upon opening the UWP executable for 3D builder in `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.3DBuilder_18.0.1931.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\` which is named as `Builder3D.exe`, using a filename as a parameter, the application just opens to the home screen.

Researching any apis/shell commands to open files using this UWP lead to nothing. I also tried to open 3D Builder using `explorer shell:AppsFolder\App_Name!App` commands, but that one does not accept parameters either.

Is there a straight forward way to open files in a UWP application by using the command line?

Comment: Try this article    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46893260/how-to-start-a-universal-windows-app-uwp-from-powershell-in-windows-10

Comment: @John The issue is that there is no way to pass any parameter to the application. That command is what I used before using the `shell:` of explorer. If I can't pass a parameter, I can't pass a file to open either.

Comment: Try something different than a UWP App. These are not made for what you are doing.